# JQuery Countdown Plugin from its div value

Tags: jquery, countdown

I am trying to modify this [JQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) plugin to initialize itself when it has a value in its *div* or *span*. I need because I'm building an application that will allow people to have any amount of countdowns on their page and they chose what the target date/time is.

As a reference, I'm doing my web app in ASP.Net, but I don't think it really matters for my problem.

The date will be coming from a Database but I will probably be converting it in seconds in the code-behind. Basically, I want to be able to throw something like

```
<div id="93" class="countdown">300</div> /* Countdown of 300 seconds, 5 minutes */
<div id="104" class="countdown">19483</div> /*Countdown of 5 hours, 24 minutes and 43 seconds */
```

and initialize all this from a single line of JQuery

```
$(".countdown").countdown();
```

or

```
$(".countdown").countdown("initializeFromValue");
```

I'm starting to get familiar with JQuery itself, but I have a hard time changing the javascript in the back. I have started creating a new part in the code. My issue here is to verify if the div has a value in integer and then initialize the value of the Countdown to that value, deleting that value after.

I have also been trying in a test page to put 4 countdown:

```
    $(function () {
        $("#countdown").countdown({ until: $("#countdown").text() });
        $("#countdown2").countdown({ until: $("#countdown2").text() });
        $("#countdown3").countdown({ until: $("#countdown3").text() });
        $("#countdown4").countdown({ until: $("#countdown4").text() });
    });
```

This is working since every countdown has an unique ID and I can also get its own text value. But it is not flexible. Can I proceed from there as well? I know for sure that

```
$(".countdown").countdown({ until: $(this).text() });
```

doesn't work because it thinks that "this" is "document".

Can someone please redirect me to some documentation/tutorial that could help me fix this problem I have? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32bitkid has the right idea. Here is why:

when you use $(".countdown") you are selecting ALL of the divs that have class countdown. YOu can even assign them to an array and iterate through with a for loop but jquery gives us the .each() syntatic sugar so the idea is

```
 $(".countdown").each(function()   //loop through all divs with countdown as class
 {
   $(this).countdown({until: $(this).text()};  // "this" is not the specific div we are 
 }                                             //iterating on
```

Hope that helps with why his method works

Comment: All three answers were good. I liked your because it explained me why and how it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".countdown").each(function(i) {
    $(this).countdown({ until: $(this).text() });
});
```

See [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) documentation at jQuery for more details. But within the scope of the closure passed to `each()`, `this` is the matched DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an each loop to create the correct context for `this`:

```
// all elements with id starting with 'countdown'
$("[id^='countdown']").each(function() {
    $(this).countdown({ until: $(this).text() });
});
```